# Will this leak?

Tags: c

calculate2 essentially does matrix calculation based on neighbors. I haven't written C in a while and I was wondering if the memcpy at every iteration was going to be a problem for memory or if I should free the tmpMatrix after every k iteration before doing a new memcpy?

```
void transform2(int *pMatrix, int iteration)
{
if(iteration == 0)
    return;

int fullLength = MATRIX_DIM * MATRIX_DIM;
int tmpMatrix[fullLength];
int start;
int row;
int col;

for(start = 0; start < iteration ; start++)
{
    memcpy(tmpMatrix, pMatrix, sizeof(pMatrix[0]) * (fullLength));

    for(row = 0; row < MATRIX_DIM ; row++)
    {
        for(col = 0; col < MATRIX_DIM ; col++)
        {
            int res = calculate2(pMatrix, tmpMatrix, row, col , iteration);
            set_at(pMatrix, res, row, col);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Also, I'm open to suggestions if you guys think there's a cleaner way of handling this. Essentially the tmpMatrix is the previous matrix at iteration-1.

P.S pMatrix is a global int *_Matrix declaration and I use free() at the end of my main for that one.

Comment: How were you planning to free `tmpMatrix`?

Comment: I wasn't planning to do anything. I thought that since I was declaring an array in function scope the execution would take care of killing it once we leave function scope since it's declared on the stack. I just want to make sure.

Comment: Pat is correct, tmpMatrix will fall out of scope once the function finishes executing.. thus no need to free it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`memcpy` does not do memory allocation, so it cannot cause a memory leak by itself <sup>1</sup>. Your allocation of `tmpMatrix` is done in the automatic storage (AKA "on the stack"), so it is not leaked in your method.

In general, you should watch out for memory leaks when you call `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`, `strdup`, and functions that return pointers to memory blocks that have been allocated dynamically.

---

<sup>1</sup> Copying data into a memory block of pointers may leak the blocks pointed to by these pointers, but not the argument that you pass to `memcpy`.

Answer (score 1):

`memcpy` does not allocate memory (in the sense of permanently, at the destination), so your code will not leak memory due to `memcpy`.

i have not checked your code otherwise, though.

Comment: Plus `tmpMatrix` is a local variable and doesn't need to be freed.